# Toyota Sienna over heating problem

Tags: toyota

my Toyota sienna is registering that its hot but using a laser thermostat shows that its not running hot , water pump has been changed along with a thermostat and new Asian coolant , also when the heater is turned on it blows cold so i am wondering if it could be a clogged heater core

Comment: The engine does not rely on the heater core for cooling - as it can be turned off. A classic "trick" to reduce overheating was to put the heater on hot to help the radiator. So, check the radiator and perhaps "flush" the system. Not sure what "asian" coolant is... Is it a recommended Toyota coolant? Do check other posts on here as they all cover points you should consider.

Comment: What did you point the laser thermostat at?

Comment: I think OP meant "Aisin" coolant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the engine is not warming up, yet it shows as hot I'd suggest replacing the coolant temperature sensor.